# Wired Connection Not Connecting - RTL8111

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

I've followed several threads and questions and seem to have found a few dead ends. I've got a fresh install and installed the most current Realtek drivers and used their `autorun.sh` script to remove the bad driver and install the new driver. No errors. I still have no connection after trying to tweak some config files. I've restored everything back to default.

What information can I provide to help resolve this? Which commands from the terminal will provide it?

What can I try to get connected?

Output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 'Ethernet'` command:

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device [1019:8116]
    Kernel driver in use: r8168
```

Comment: Debian is off topic here. Or did you add the [tag:debian] tag accidentally?

Comment: @DavidFoerster  I figured it may apply to Debian as well, so I added it...if it's off topic, then it should be removed as a tag, no?

Comment: Look at the tag description: “These questions should be about how Ubuntu and Debian work together from a workflow perspective.” The [tag:debian] tag isn't meant for questions that merely may also apply to Debian and I understand that was your intention.

Comment: @DavidFoerster output added

Comment: Ok, the device driver itself seems to be in order, so we need to probe deeper: could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? Thanks.

Comment: add results of `ifconfig -a`